# video sequence editor, footage strip opacity

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I am doing editing with blender video sequencer and I found you can't dial down the opacity of a strip or it doesn't work when you've already applied a strip speed control effect.

Comment: Need a little more information than that - what have you tried? Which buttons? Which version? Have you tried other versions? ...

Comment: If you have one effect over the video strip you can't add another, use a meta-strip instead. Please read this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27835/how-to-use-multiple-effect-strips-in-blender-video-sequence-editor/27853#27853

Answer (score 3):

Pick the effect strip instead of the source strip; then alter its opacity.