# How to use multiple Effect Strips in Blender Video Sequence Editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I noticed that adding a second Effect Strip to a video sequence negates the effect of the former Effect Strip, eg. adding by Speed, the result does not include the Transform effect.

What is the reasoning behind such behavior? Is there any workaround other than rendering the sequence with one effect and then re-rendering is with another effect etc? That would be very cumbersome.

[image: effect strips]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using a **meta strip**. Select the layers you want to apply the speed to and press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd>** (or go tho the menu Strip->Make meta Strip) That will create a new strip that contains the selected strips.

Then you set a speed strip (or whatever other effect you want) on top of the meta strip.

[image]

Quote from the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Meta:Sanbox/Doc:2.6/Manual/Sequencer/Strips/Types):

> A Meta Strip is a strip which contain several strips. It's like a Group of strips, working the similar way as Nodes groups. It allows you to reduce significantly the (vertical) space used in the sequencer, and treat multiple strips as if it was one strip. You can move, resize, and edit properties exactly the same way strips are. (see Editing and deleting strips page for more informations.)
>
> You can edit the content of a Meta Strip by pressing ⇆ Tab; It will unwrap the content temporarily and hide any other strips present on the workspace, allowing you to select, move and resize the contained strips, or edit their properties. Press ⇆ Tab again to re-wrap the strips into one Meta Strip.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. So let's say, if I'd like to combine 4 effects, I have to make meta strip out of the source file and the first effect, then apply second effect, then make meta strip out of that, then apply third effect etc.? I mean, are there "nested" meta strips possible? Meta strips inside meta strips? Or combining more than two effects is simply impossible?

Comment: Yes you can nest metastrips within other metastrips..

Comment: Generally speaking you should be able to stack effects upon each other, it's just the speed effect that breaks the rule.

Answer (score 2):

Try applying the effect to the effect rather than to the original clip.

I dunno about your transform-strip - but I just realised that rather than applying a cross to two videoclips that are both sped up (which won't work), I needed to do the cross between the speed strips instead, and now it works as expected.

Comment: Hey thanks that worked! (For me I needed alpha over and transform, so first I made the transform, then for the alpha over  Iselected the bottom-video clip, then the TRANSFORM effect strip, instead of the picture itself, and it worked :))

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that you can get a bit lost in meta-strip-ception. That is deep meta strip embeds. You step in by selecting the metastrip and Tab keying. But they all look similar.

I suggest that you carefully name metastrips via properties and even add a simple color strip below the active video strip. This is to give you a visual que as to which meta you are inside.

Comment: Also keep in mind that adding layers of complexity to a project will result in extra processing and you'll experience some slowness in your computer's performance