# Combining speed control and transform effect strips

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have a video that I want to trim and rescale, and also slow down by a factor of 2. I am able to do this separately, but I can't find the way to combine all the effects. What am I missing?

Comment: To increase clarity please include a screen snaphot of the VSE.  Please isolate, if more clear,  the situation to one video strip transformed in a new Blender file.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27835/how-to-use-multiple-effect-strips-in-blender-video-sequence-editor/27839#27839

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're asking without some pictures, but I think you're adding all the effects strips to the original footage. This doesn't work when you're trying to combine more than one effect on the same section of footage. See the following example:

[image]

In this (contrived) example, I have a Gamma Cross, a Transform, and a Glow effect that I want to all be applied to that transition between the two strips. If you select one of the purple strips and add each effect to it, then the only effect that will actually be applied is whatever effect is on top.

In order to have all the effects combined the way you expect, you would add the Gamma Cross like normal, then select the Gamma Cross and add the Transform to the Gamma Cross strip, then select the Transform and add the Glow to the Transform strip. This will make each effect combine with the others the way you'd expect them to.

Comment: The example you wrote is quite similar to my case. In the end, the key is to add the next effect strip **having previously selected** the effect at the top. This makes the input of the new strip be the strip directly below. However, I have no idea if changing the input of an existing strip is possible. Blender is very powerful, but so counterintuitive at the same time...

Comment: You're quite right, and that's what I tried to describe. I know that it's possible to change the input of a given strip, but I've not had good success with that. It's proved to be much simpler to just delete the incorrect strip and replace it.

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/132468/121702) to ["How to change effect strip input in Video Editor?"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/128240/121702) explains how inputs of existing strips can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to combine multiple effects you have to think of it as a "stack".
An example:

```
Strip0: Image strip
```

add a solid color (shift+a) that we will use to fade-in from black:

```
Strip1: Effect strip > Color (black)
Strip0: Image strip
```

now add a Gamma cross for the fade-in by selecting first the strip0 and then strip1 (if you first select strip1 you have fade-out ;-) ) and shift+a to add Gamma cross:

```
Strip2: Effect strip > Gamma cross
Strip1: Effect strip > Color (black)
Strip0: Image strip
```

now we want to add a zoom but still have our gamma cross effect (fade-in) working). Well select the Gamma cross from Strip2 and do shift+a and add Transform to zoom in.

```
Strip3: Effect strip > transform (for zoom)
Strip2: Effect strip > Gamma cross
Strip1: Effect strip > Color (black)
Strip0: Image strip
```

Now you have a zoomed in image with a black fade-in.

So think of it of trying to select always the top-most element.
It can happen that you need to grab some strips and change the vertical order (press g and y when strip is selected) to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

- **Lengthen** the size of the trimmed video to double its horizontal size... this will allow for all of the video to play at half the speed.
- Place all your transform strips on top of one another ... you may need to take  59 seconds to delete your old work.  Only the last strip should have alpha of 1.00 visible.  The other strips should have alpha 0.0 not visible.  The last effect strip will have the combined effects and it alone is visible.
- In the very worst case. Place the video on the timeline, No transforms, Test. Reduce the complication.  Next trim and test. Next Only change speed, test.  To determine where are steps first fail.  You should have a clear list of what succeeds and fails.

Comment: I can't get it right. I have the video, the transform, and the speed control on channels 1, 2 and 3 respectively. There is no difference when I change the opacity. The blend modes are on 'replace' for the effects. What else?

Comment: See lengthen instruction please

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to this,

1. Trim the initial video and then apply the speed control effector as length in settings
   to the trimmed side.
2. Or you can simply use the speed control effectors speed multiple setting on the trimmed part of the original video.

Hope this helps.

In both cases you have got to trim the original video and use effectors seperately on it.