# How to change effect strip input in Video Editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, effects

Let's say I have a cross fade track from **Track A** to **Track B**.
Now I decide to create a gaussian blue effect strip over **Track A**, let's call it **Track C**
Now I want the cross fade from **Track C** to **Track B**, but i can't change the "Input 1" parameter from the cross fade track because it's grayed out.

Do I really have to create the effect again? Or is there a better way to solve this problem?

I just started learning blender, so sorry if i'm using the wrong terms and this question is already answered.

Answer (score 3):

To change **input1** parameter:

1. Select strip you want to make an input
2. Shift+right click to select strip with input you want to change
3. Press Strip -> Reassign inputs (or just hit "r" as a shortcut)
   Hope this helps.