# Video Sequence Editor Alpha Over png transparency speed control effect

Tags: video-sequence-editor, effects

I'm a newbie with Blender and maybe this is a duplicate, but I couldn't figure out how to solve my issue. I'm using v2.69 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I try to make a demo video, where I have a strip on `ch1` above a `*.png` on `ch4` which has a text with alpha background. I want to speed up the video while having the text over it. I could speed up by adding the `Speed Control` effect and separately I am able to add the `Alpha Over`.

My issue is that if I put both effects, then the speed control is not applied. I found a post about this [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-308764.html) but it is still not working:

- ch1 my_video
- ch2 `speed control` (blend: over drop; multiply speed:1.5;
  other setup default) - effect applied on ch1 strip
- ch4 my.png
- ch5 `alpha over` (all default setup) - effect applied on video and
  image.

Can somebody tell me how should I set up so both effects are applied? Does it matter the order of applying effects? Do I have to change some setting elsewhere?

Comment: To add multiple effects in the VSE use meta strips read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27835/how-to-use-multiple-effect-strips-in-blender-video-sequence-editor/27839#27839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Actually, it was easy and very intuitive.
First, I added the video and image strips, in the image strip properties chanced to `Blend: Alpha Over` and next I add the `speed control` to the video file (only changed `multiplayer` property, the others are left default).

No need to add `Alpha Over` effect separately.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues adding text on top of a video AND applying the speed control. 
I worked around the problem by creating a metastrip (CTRL+G of the text and video strip) and then adding the video control.